# Binary representation starting with a least significant bit in C

Tags: c, function, bit

I'm trying to make a binary representation of an integer using `binary()` function and then use `reverse()` function to get bit reversal as can be seen below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char reverse(unsigned char b) {
    b = (b & 0xF0) >> 4 | (b & 0x0F) << 4;
    b = (b & 0xCC) >> 2 | (b & 0x33) << 2;
    b = (b & 0xAA) >> 1 | (b & 0x55) << 1;
    return b;
}

int binary(int n)
{
    int b;

    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        b = (n % 2) + 10 * binary(n / 2);
        unsigned char i = (unsigned char)b;
        return reverse(i);

    }

}

int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("The binary equivalent of %d is %d\n", n, binary(n));
  return 0;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that I expect `binary()` to produce a binary number (for example, a binary representation fo `18` would be `10010`), and then `reverse()` function to take this number and produce a reversed binary representation starting with the least significant bit (LSB) which should be `01001` in this case. However, when I try to run it, I get returned 0.

I'm new to C and I'm thinking maybe the issue is in the `unsigned char` datatype, but when, why if I convert `b` into `unsigned char` it still doesn't work?

Comment: This can already not work if you are trying to return a `int`. A representation of a number is a sequence of characters (digits), so what you want is to construct and return a string. Please also be aware that C++ is a different language than C. Don't tag unrelated languages.

Comment: An unsigned char can only hold numbers up to 255.  You need to use int for your binary representation.  `reverse` will not work on the binary number, only the unsigned char.

Comment: Re "*An unsigned char can only hold numbers up to 255*", ...on conventional modern systems.

Answer (score 0):

When reversing the bits, all you have to do is check the LSB. Add that value to an output variable. Then shift the output variable by one to the left and shift the original number by one to the right. In the mathematical example below, I do a first 0 shift so it become easier on the eye with the formatting.

In your example of 10010:

```
Round 1: output = (00000 << 1) + (10010 & 1) = 00000
         N      = 10010 >> 1                 = 01001

Round 2: output = (00000 << 1) + (01001 & 1) = 00001
         N      = 01001 >> 1                 = 00100

Round 3: output = (00001 << 1) + (00100 & 1) = 00010
         N      = 00100 >> 1                 = 00010

Round 4: output = (00010 << 1) + (0010 & 1)  = 00100
         N      = 00010 >> 1                 = 00001

Round 5: output = (00100 << 1) + (00001 & 1) = 01001
         N      = 00001 >> 1                 = 00000
```

**Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int binary(int n)
{
    int output = 0;

    if ( n == 0 ) return 0;

    // Save one left shift    
    output += n & 1; 
    n = n >> 1;

    while( n != 0 ){
        output = output << 1;
        output += n & 1; 
        n = n >> 1;
        printf("%d\n", output);
    }

    return output;
}

void printBin(int n){
    char bin[33] = {0};

    for (int i = 31; i > -1; i-- ){
        bin[i] = (char)((n & 1) ^ 48);
        n = n >> 1;
    }
    puts(bin);
}


int main()
{
    int n; int rb;
    printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    rb = binary(n);

    printf("The binary equivalent of %d is %d\n", n, rb);

    printf("%11d:", n);
    printBin(n);

    printf("%11d:", rb);
    printBin(rb);

    return 0;
}
```